# Change Position of textOn and textOff in Android Swtich

Tags: android, android-xml

I have implemented the Switch Widget this way:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textOff="@string/switch_on"
            android:textOn="@string/switch_on"
            app:showText="true"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:thumb="@drawable/slider_thumb"
            app:switchMinWidth="200dp"
            app:track="@drawable/slider_tracker">
```

Everything works fine, except that the text is written on top on the thumb. What i want t achieve is having the text displayed on the track. So, assuming the switch is checked, the text would be displayed on the left and when not checked, the textOff would be displayed on the right.

[image: Something like the image]
.

How can i achieve this. Thanks

Comment: I strongly suspect that the answer is for you to write your own `CompoundButton` that does this, or see if there is some existing library that offers this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out i can achieve this by drawing a text on a bitmap, generate a bitmap drawable from that and change the track drawable of the switch to the bitmapdrawable.

Basically, i achieve this with the snippet below.

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(drawTextToBitmap(this, R.drawable.test_, "Slide to Sign In"));
        switchCompat.setTrackDrawable(bitmapDrawable);

 public Bitmap drawTextToBitmap(Context gContext,
                                   int gResId,
                                   String gText) {
        Resources resources = gContext.getResources();
        float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
        Bitmap bitmap =
                BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, gResId);

        android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig =
                bitmap.getConfig();
        // set default bitmap config if none
        if (bitmapConfig == null) {
            bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        }
        // resource bitmaps are imutable,
        // so we need to convert it to mutable one
        bitmap = bitmap.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        // new antialised Paint
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        // text color - #3D3D3D
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(61, 61, 61));
        // text size in pixels
        paint.setTextSize((int) (10 * scale));
        // text shadow
        paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE);

        // draw text to the Canvas center
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(gText, 0, gText.length(), bounds);
        int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - (170));
        int y = (bitmap.getHeight() + bounds.height()) / 2;

        canvas.drawText(gText, x, y, paint);

        return bitmap;
    }
```

As for changing the drawable when the the switch is on and off,you can play with that using

```
switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });
```